# How can i enable Canonical Partner in elementary Juno or Is there an application of a similar sort ?

Tags: updates, graphic-drivers, drivers, appcenter, gui-toolkits

I needed to update driver. "I was looking for a GUI based alternative"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `software-properties-common` and `software-properties-gtk` packages.

Use this command.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
```

After installation is complete, you can just search for 'software and updates' in start menu.